# How can I allow div scroll to be auto scrolled to the bottom on page load and allow user to scroll up if needed?

Tags: javascript, css

I have below codes which helps me to scroll to the bottom of my div, but as it seems it does not allow me to scroll up, so my div has dynamic data which need to be scrolled.
I tried to search over google but no luck.

```
<script>
var delayInMilliseconds = 5000;
setInterval(function() {

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#message').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#message')[0].scrollHeight}, 5000);
});
}, delayInMilliseconds);
</script>
```

How can I allow div scroll to be auto scrolled to the bottom on page load and allow user to scroll up if needed?

Thank you

Comment: So why is it in an interval? Why is there a document ready inside of the interval?

Comment: interval because my div has dynamic data, every time it displays data

Comment: Are you saying after it scrolls automatically to the bottom, you want to be able to manually scroll back up? And it won't let you?

Comment: You could scroll the bottom *only* whenever you receive new dynamic data. Lose the interval and show us your code which fetches, receives and shows the dynamic data.

Comment: Yes, I need to be allowed to scroll up after scroll to the bottom, and to auto scroll if scroll is at bottom

Comment: not really sure of the goal, but to allow manual scrolling, maybe try adding to your document ready function, something like: 
$('#message').css({ overflow: 'scroll'});

Comment: That codes add horizontal scroll

Comment: Why not just call it when you update it instead of just doing it all the time?

Comment: Do you mean to add ajax which will check new update and then scroll or there is other approach?

Comment: So it did let you scroll but horizontally? you could try "overflow-y" for vertical only: $('#message').css({ overflow-y: 'scroll'});

Comment: If I add that codes you provided in my codes, it stops auto scroll to the bottom